# Ubuntu 12.10 Can't find my Creative Bluetooth Speaker (D200)

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, speakers

I hope someone can help. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. I recently bought a bluetooth speaker (creative D200). When I search for bluetooth devices on my laptop (Gazelle Professional from System76. with  Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 - 802.11A/B/G/N Wireless LAN + Bluetooth Combo Module.) my speaker will not show up.

I know my speaker works, since I can connect it to my phone. I also know that bluetooth works on my laptop as I can find my phone with it. However, my laptop cannot find my speaker. I have tried with blueman and the standard bluetooth manager many many times. I wondered if I need some sort of driver or if anyone has fixed this same problem.

Thanks, Declan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often better to research your subject before posting it on Askubuntu.
Here is an article that answers directly your question : [Creative D200 on Linux](http://dakotux.wordpress.com/2011/03/27/creative-d200-on-linux/).

Here is a detailed tutorial based on that article :

1. Scan for bluetooth devices
2. Press the bluetooth button behind the speaker during the search for 3 seconds
3. Once it shows up on the list, choose PIN options
4. Choose `0000` as the PIN
5. Connect to the speaker
6. Go to System settings> Sound settings
7. Choose Creative D200 as default speaker in the `Output` tab.

Comment: Hey. That did it. I honestly did do some research, I've been 2 days scratching my head. I guess I just need to up my research game. Thanks.